# Python requests - print entire http request (raw)?

Tags: python, http, python-requests

While using the [`requests` module](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), is there any way to print the raw HTTP request?

I don't want just the headers, I want the request line, headers, and content printout. Is it possible to see what ultimately is constructed from HTTP request?

Comment: That's a good question. From looking at the source, it doesn't seem like there is any way to obtain the raw content of a prepared request, and it's only serialized when it's sent. That seems like it would be a good feature.

Comment: Well, you could also start wireshark and see it that way.

Comment: @qwrrty it would be difficult to integrate this as a `requests` feature, as it would mean rewritting/bypassing `urllib3` and `httplib`. See the stack trace below

Comment: This worked for me - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588644/how-can-i-see-the-entire-http-request-thats-being-sent-by-my-python-application

Comment: The logging answer linked by Ajay is really a helpful method.

Answer (score 324, accepted):

[Since v1.2.3](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.PreparedRequest) Requests added the PreparedRequest object. As per the documentation "it contains the exact bytes that will be sent to the server".

One can use this to pretty print a request, like so:

```
import requests

req = requests.Request('POST','http://stackoverflow.com',headers={'X-Custom':'Test'},data='a=1&b=2')
prepared = req.prepare()

def pretty_print_POST(req):
    """
    At this point it is completely built and ready
    to be fired; it is "prepared".

    However pay attention at the formatting used in 
    this function because it is programmed to be pretty 
    printed and may differ from the actual request.
    """
    print('{}\n{}\r\n{}\r\n\r\n{}'.format(
        '-----------START-----------',
        req.method + ' ' + req.url,
        '\r\n'.join('{}: {}'.format(k, v) for k, v in req.headers.items()),
        req.body,
    ))

pretty_print_POST(prepared)
```

which produces:

```
-----------START-----------
POST http://stackoverflow.com/
Content-Length: 7
X-Custom: Test

a=1&b=2
```

Then you can send the actual request with this:

```
s = requests.Session()
s.send(prepared)
```

These links are to the latest documentation available, so they might change in content:
[Advanced - Prepared requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#prepared-requests) and [API - Lower level classes](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#lower-level-classes)

Comment: This seems to [have been added on `2.0.0`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests), though, not `1.2.3`

Comment: @goncalopp I saw it mentioned in the documentation for 1.2.3, but I didn't look at the code. If you can confirm it was not present until 2.0.0 I'll change it to avoid confusion.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I think there's a typo: in the function definition, the argument should be 'prepared', 'not 'req'.

Comment: If you use the simple `response = requests.post(...)` (or `requests.get` or `requests.put`, etc) methods, you can actually get the `PreparedResponse` through `response.request`. It can save the work of manually manipulating `requests.Request` and `requests.Session`, if you don't need to access the raw http data before you receive a response.

Comment: what about the HTTP protocol version part just after the url? like 'HTTP/1.1' ? that is not found when print out using your pretty printer.

Comment: Updated to use CRLF, since that's what RFC 2616 requires, and it could be an issue for very strict parsers

Comment: Suggest replacing `req.body` with `str(req.body, 'UTF-8'),` so that multipart files will print prettily with all their boundaries and stuff.

Comment: Suggest replacing `req.body by `req.body if req.body else ''`. Otherwise, it prints `None` if there is nothing. It seems to me that it would be better to really print nothing at all.

Comment: @Gershom Great tip, however, I just wanted to say I am incredibly grateful for this being illustrated as-is because it gives full control over the verb/headers/etc. For my use-case, there is no prefab solution within requests (HTTP PURGE)

Comment: When trying to write this function output to file, a content was saved with double carriage return. \r should be omitted from the formatting line. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4025988/1100913 for more details.

Comment: This is wrong. `http://stackoverflow.com/` shouldn't be there. And is missing `HTTP/1.1`. This isn't valid HTTP request string.

Comment: 'Request' object has no attribute 'body'...

Comment: @ntg Well, then we all know you typed `pretty_print_POST(req)` rather than what is actually there (`pretty_print_POST(prepared)`.  It takes a PreparedRequest, not a Request.

Comment: @Noumenon this does not work for me. Only thing that did was using this `from urllib.parse import uquote`, then `unquote(req.body)` https://www.urldecoder.io/python/

Answer (score 223):

```
import requests

response = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data={'key1': 'value1'})
print(response.request.url)
print(response.request.body)
print(response.request.headers)
```

[`Response`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response) objects have a [`.request` property](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response.request) which is the [`PreparedRequest`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.PreparedRequest) object that was sent.

Comment: Note that in case of redirections the `response.request` will actually contain the **last** `PreparedRequest` that has been sent. Try it with `https://httpbin.org/redirect/3`. To really dig out the original request from the response object you have to look in the `response.history`.

Comment: If the request throws an exception, this won't work.

Answer (score 68):

An even better idea is to use the requests_toolbelt library, which can dump out both requests and responses as strings for you to print to the console. It handles all the tricky cases with files and encodings which the above solution does not handle well.

It's as easy as this:

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.utils import dump

resp = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/redirect/5')
data = dump.dump_all(resp)
print(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

Source: https://toolbelt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dumputils.html

You can simply install it by typing:

```
pip install requests_toolbelt
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to dump the request without sending it, though.

Comment: dump_all does not appear to work properly as I get "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'UUID' objects" from the call.

Comment: @rtaft: Please report this as a bug in their github repository: https://github.com/sigmavirus24/requests-toolbelt/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen

Comment: It prints the dump with > and < signs, are they part of the actual request?

Comment: @DobesVandermeer there is an undocumented private function _dump_request_data that might do the trick

https://github.com/requests/toolbelt/blob/master/requests_toolbelt/utils/dump.py#L57

Comment: @Jay It looks like they are prepended to the actual request/response for appearance

(https://github.com/requests/toolbelt/blob/master/requests_toolbelt/utils/dump.py#L103)

and can be specified by passing request_prefix=b'{some_request_prefix}', response_prefix=b'{some_response_prefix}' to dump_all

(https://github.com/requests/toolbelt/blob/master/requests_toolbelt/utils/dump.py#L161)

Answer (score 50):

**Note: this answer is for older versions of `requests`, when this functionality was missing. Newer versions support this natively (see other answers)**

It's not possible to get the *true* raw content of the request out of `requests`, since it only deals with higher level objects, such as *headers* and *method type*. `requests` uses `urllib3` to send requests, but `urllib3` *also* doesn't deal with raw data - it uses `httplib`. Here's a representative stack trace of a request:

```
-> r= requests.get("http://google.com")
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py(55)get()
-> return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py(44)request()
-> return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py(382)request()
-> resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py(485)send()
-> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py(324)send()
-> timeout=timeout
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py(478)urlopen()
-> body=body, headers=headers)
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py(285)_make_request()
-> conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  /usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py(958)request()
-> self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
```

Inside the `httplib` machinery, we can see `HTTPConnection._send_request` indirectly uses `HTTPConnection._send_output`, which finally creates the raw request *and* body (if it exists), and uses `HTTPConnection.send` to send them separately. `send` finally reaches the socket.

Since there's no hooks for doing what you want, as a last resort you can monkey patch `httplib` to get the content. It's a fragile solution, and you may need to adapt it if `httplib` is changed. If you intend to distribute software using this solution, you may want to consider packaging `httplib` instead of using the system's, which is easy, since it's a pure python module.

Alas, without further ado, the solution:

```
import requests
import httplib

def patch_send():
    old_send= httplib.HTTPConnection.send
    def new_send( self, data ):
        print data
        return old_send(self, data) #return is not necessary, but never hurts, in case the library is changed
    httplib.HTTPConnection.send= new_send

patch_send()
requests.get("http://www.python.org")
```

which yields the output:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.python.org
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.1.0 CPython/2.7.3 Linux/3.2.0-23-generic-pae
```

Comment: Hi goncalopp, if I call the patch_send() procedure a 2nd time (after a 2nd request), then it prints the data twice (so 2x times the output like you have shown above) ? So, if I would do a 3rd request, it would print it 3x times and so on... Any idea how to get only the output once ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @opstalj you shouldn't call `patch_send` multiple times, only once, after importing `httplib`

Comment: BTW, how did you get the stacktrace? Is it done by tracing the code or is there a trick?

Comment: @huggie no trick, just patience, manual stepping and reading the files

Comment: For python 3, replace httplib with http.client

Comment: @loopbackbee, i like this solution for peeking at what urls are being called under the hood so that i can mock them with requests_mocker later. Would be cool if you had a `patch_receive` to peek at the responses too!

Answer (score 24):

`requests` supports so called [event hooks](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#event-hooks) (as of 2.23 there's actually only `response` hook). The hook can be used on a request to print full request-response pair's data, including effective URL, headers and bodies, like:

```py
import textwrap
import requests

def print_roundtrip(response, *args, **kwargs):
    format_headers = lambda d: '\n'.join(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in d.items())
    print(textwrap.dedent('''
        ---------------- request ----------------
        {req.method} {req.url}
        {reqhdrs}

        {req.body}
        ---------------- response ----------------
        {res.status_code} {res.reason} {res.url}
        {reshdrs}

        {res.text}
    ''').format(
        req=response.request, 
        res=response, 
        reqhdrs=format_headers(response.request.headers), 
        reshdrs=format_headers(response.headers), 
    ))

requests.get('https://httpbin.org/', hooks={'response': print_roundtrip})
```

Running it prints:

```
---------------- request ----------------
GET https://httpbin.org/
User-Agent: python-requests/2.23.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive

None
---------------- response ----------------
200 OK https://httpbin.org/
Date: Thu, 14 May 2020 17:16:13 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 9593
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
...
</html>
```

You may want to change `res.text` to `res.content` if the response is binary.

Comment: This is the best modern method.

Comment: Very nice solution using only built in modules!

Answer (score 8):

Here is a code, which makes the same, but with response headers:

```
import socket
def patch_requests():
    old_readline = socket._fileobject.readline
    if not hasattr(old_readline, 'patched'):
        def new_readline(self, size=-1):
            res = old_readline(self, size)
            print res,
            return res
        new_readline.patched = True
        socket._fileobject.readline = new_readline
patch_requests()
```

I spent a lot of time searching for this, so I'm leaving it here, if someone needs.

Answer (score 5):

[A fork of @AntonioHerraizS answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23816211/3191896) (HTTP version missing as stated in comments)

---

Use this code to get a string representing the raw HTTP packet without sending it:

```py
import requests


def get_raw_request(request):
    request = request.prepare() if isinstance(request, requests.Request) else request
    headers = '\r\n'.join(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in request.headers.items())
    body = '' if request.body is None else request.body.decode() if isinstance(request.body, bytes) else request.body
    return f'{request.method} {request.path_url} HTTP/1.1\r\n{headers}\r\n\r\n{body}'


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Test'}
request = requests.Request('POST', 'https://stackoverflow.com', headers=headers, json={"hello": "world"})
raw_request = get_raw_request(request)
print(raw_request)
```

Result:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Test
Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: application/json

{"hello": "world"}
```

> Can also print the request in the response object
>
> ```
> r = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
> raw_request = get_raw_request(r.request)
> print(raw_request)
> ```

Comment: Just to note: `requests.request` (lowercase `r`) is `def request(...)` which is a function that "Constructs and sends a :class:Request <Request>" https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/4f3f189/src/requests/api.py#L14; while `requests.Request` (uppercase `R`) is `class Request(...)` which is "A user-created :class:`Request <Request>` object"  https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/4f3f189/src/requests/models.py#L230

Answer (score 3):

I use the following function to format requests. It's like @AntonioHerraizS except it will pretty-print JSON objects in the body as well, and it labels all parts of the request.

```
format_json = functools.partial(json.dumps, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
indent = functools.partial(textwrap.indent, prefix='  ')

def format_prepared_request(req):
    """Pretty-format 'requests.PreparedRequest'

    Example:
        res = requests.post(...)
        print(format_prepared_request(res.request))

        req = requests.Request(...)
        req = req.prepare()
        print(format_prepared_request(res.request))
    """
    headers = '\n'.join(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in req.headers.items())
    content_type = req.headers.get('Content-Type', '')
    if 'application/json' in content_type:
        try:
            body = format_json(json.loads(req.body))
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            body = req.body
    else:
        body = req.body
    s = textwrap.dedent("""
    REQUEST
    =======
    endpoint: {method} {url}
    headers:
    {headers}
    body:
    {body}
    =======
    """).strip()
    s = s.format(
        method=req.method,
        url=req.url,
        headers=indent(headers),
        body=indent(body),
    )
    return s
```

And I have a similar function to format the response:

```
def format_response(resp):
    """Pretty-format 'requests.Response'"""
    headers = '\n'.join(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in resp.headers.items())
    content_type = resp.headers.get('Content-Type', '')
    if 'application/json' in content_type:
        try:
            body = format_json(resp.json())
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            body = resp.text
    else:
        body = resp.text
    s = textwrap.dedent("""
    RESPONSE
    ========
    status_code: {status_code}
    headers:
    {headers}
    body:
    {body}
    ========
    """).strip()

    s = s.format(
        status_code=resp.status_code,
        headers=indent(headers),
        body=indent(body),
    )
    return s
```

Answer (score 1):

test_print.py content:

```
import logging
import pytest
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.utils import dump


def print_raw_http(response):
    data = dump.dump_all(response, request_prefix=b'', response_prefix=b'')
    return '\n' * 2 + data.decode('utf-8')

@pytest.fixture
def logger():
    log = logging.getLogger()
    log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    return log

def test_print_response(logger):
    session = requests.Session()
    response = session.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/')
    assert response.status_code == 300, logger.warning(print_raw_http(response))
```

hello.py content:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Run:

```
 $ python -m flask hello.py
 $ python -m pytest test_print.py
```

Stdout:

```
------------------------------ Captured log call ------------------------------
DEBUG    urllib3.connectionpool:connectionpool.py:225 Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1:5000
DEBUG    urllib3.connectionpool:connectionpool.py:437 http://127.0.0.1:5000 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 13
WARNING  root:test_print_raw_response.py:25 

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
User-Agent: python-requests/2.23.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive


HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 13
Server: Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.6.8
Date: Thu, 24 Sep 2020 21:00:54 GMT

Hello, World!
```