# Reading HTML from a website returning 403 forbidden

Tags: java, html, web-scraping

I'm attempting to write a web scraper here and the website is returning a 403 forbidden to my code even though it is an accessible webpage through a browser.  My main question is: is this something that they set up on the website to discourage web scraping or am I doing something wrong?

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.pcgs.com/prices/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

If I change the url to a website like http://www.google.com then it will return html.  If the site is blocking it is there a way around that?  Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes. You're doing something they are actively discouraging. Sure, you could probably use a tool like selenium to bypass it... but when/if they detect it they'll probably block your IP address.

Comment: Thank you, I decided the better route would be to find a page that doesn't block my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web server may contain a code to block not authorized user-agent.

I guess you can verify this by making sure your program will send a standard User-Agent value (i.e. corresponding to an existing web browser) and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Sometimes this is the case, but unlikely to be the case here; see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know much Java, but this simple Python code worked when I tried it without an error, saving the content as it appeared in my browser:

```
import requests                                                                            

r = requests.get('http://www.pcgs.com/prices/')    

with open('out.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

This sends a [slightly unusual, non-browser user-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658572/python-requests-print-entire-http-request-raw).

So, if their site isn't likely blocking you on the basis of user-agent, maybe you've hit the site too quickly and they've blocked your IP address or rate limited you? If you're intending on scraping sites, you should be [nice and limit the number of requests you make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022030/web-scraping-etiquette).

Another thing you can do before scraping is check for a site's [`robots.txt`](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html); like this one for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt); that explicitly declares what the site's policies are towards automated scrapers. (In this case, the PCGS site doesn't appear to have one.)