# Set name header of multipart-encoded file POST

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to upload a file to a form but I'm getting back an error from the Tomcat server saying:

> The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23816211/2291321) I've managed to print the request that I'm making and when comparing it to the request made in the browser I've noticed that the request payload `name` is not aligned so I'm guessing this is my issue.

The Requests [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) for POSTing multipart-encoded files shows that you can override the filename, content_type and headers explicitly:

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> files = {'file': ('report.xls', open('report.xls', 'rb'), 'application/vnd.ms-excel', {'Expires': '0'})}
```

This seems to work fine but as mentioned above, I also need to set the `name` as well as the `filename` and the `content-type`.

Digging around on the GitHub repo I found the `_encode_files` method in [models.py](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/6da438dabd6f5aeed23f77fd663d4092506ec8b3/requests/models.py) which seems to allow for specifying the `name`:

```
rf = RequestField(name=k, data=fp.read(),
                  filename=fn, headers=fh)
```

But I can't seem to get this to work and in my application, as with the above example, I have filename specified before the reference to the file:

```
files = {'file': (filename, open(filePath, 'rb'), 'application/x-zip-compressed')}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name is set from the key in your `files` dictionary. Just alter that key to set the name field to the desired value:

```
>>> import requests
>>> files = {'foobar': ('foo.txt', 'foo\ncontents\n','text/plain')}
>>> req = requests.Request('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', files=files).prepare()
>>> print req.body
--49773910d9514216894b697cb70e9f21
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foobar"; filename="foo.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

foo
contents

--49773910d9514216894b697cb70e9f21--
```

Note the `name="foobar"` element of the per-part `Content-Disposition` header.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't spot that. Thanks