# requests module : post data to remote host, wrong value is sent

Tags: python

I have string  like:

```
{
    'singleQuesResponses': {
        '28': '',
        '14': '',
        '27': '',
        '26': ''
    },
    'org_apache_struts_taglib_html_TOKEN': 'a1553f25303435076412b5ca7299b936',
    'quesResponses': {
        'some': 'data'
    }
}
```

when i post it in python requests like:

```
data = json.loads(data)
page = requests.post('http://localhost/chilivery/index.php', data=data, cookies=bcookies)
```

then value that post is something like this:

```
array(3) { ["quesResponses"]=> string(4) "some" ["singleQuesResponses"]=> string(2) "14" ["org_apache_struts_taglib_html_TOKEN"]=> string(32) "a1553f25303435076412b5ca7299b936" }
```

but i expect:

```
array(3) { ["quesResponses"]=> array["some"=>'data'] ["singleQuesResponses"]=> string(2) "14" ["org_apache_struts_taglib_html_TOKEN"]=> string(32) "a1553f25303435076412b5ca7299b936" }
```

I mean why 'some' is not sent by value as array and the only first key of it send as a string ?

Comment: This doesn't look like django... are you sure its not php?..

Comment: i send data with requests.post django to php remote

Comment: Looks like a bug somewhere with inner dicts in your data. Maybe have a network trace to see what is actually sent over the network, that will identity which side has the bug (your code or PHP on the other side.

Comment: @Guillaume the php in other  side is just a dd($_POST)

Comment: Sayse seems right, this question does not concern the Django framework (even though you may be working with it). It is rather about the `requests` module.

Comment: @MarAja django tag is removed

Comment: @ user272426  you should probably try to set the header of your HTTP POST request to `{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}` and use the json module to dump your data before posting. In practice use the following line to post your data: `requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`

Comment: @MarAja it return array(0) { }

Comment: @user272426 Damn, how are you reading your data on the PHP side?

Comment: @MarAja dd($_POST)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, only way is sending your data with `Get` instead of posting them with data; you can use params in requests module.

Answer (score 0):

That's how it's supposed to work. The setting the data params as a dict will make the requests module attempt to send it with:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

It will only take the first level of the dictionary and encode it in the body as x=data&y=other_data.

You should either encode your object with json.dumps(data) or assign it to the json argument directly.

```
requests.post(url, json=data)
```

This sets the Content-Type header to application/json

OR

```
requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data))
```

This won't set the Content-Type header.

Comment: requests.post(url, json=data) will not send anything

Comment: requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data)) this will not send with value only the key will be send as I said in question

Comment: What's your data object? Is it a python dictionary, or a json string? If its already a json string, you are not doing anything wrong on the python side. What you can do to debug your request is to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658572/python-requests-print-entire-http-request-raw)

Comment: it is string json.loads(data) to make it valid json

Comment: json.dumps(data) converts a python dict to json string, json.loads converts json string back to python object. If you can update your question with the exact code you are using to prepare your data, maybe I can point your mistake.

Comment: my code only works when the header is set to Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded , is this problem ?