# What is the equivalent curl command of python requests?

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I have the following python code.

```
import requests
response = requests.request("POST"
        , url = "https://services27.ieee.org/fellowsdirectory/getpageresultsdesk.html"
        , data = {
            'pageNum': 3
            }   
        )

print(response.text)
```

But I can not figure the equivalent curl command. Does anybody know the equivalent curl command?

```
curl -X POST -d '{"pageNum": "3"}' https://services27.ieee.org/fellowsdirectory/getpageresultsdesk.html
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are passing in `data` is a dictionnary with the form url encoded parameters as key/value, this is not JSON data, check [this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.7/user/quickstart/#make-a-post-request)

Your python code will send the following request :

```
POST https://services27.ieee.org/fellowsdirectory/getpageresultsdesk.html
Host: services27.ieee.org
Content-Length: 9
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

pageNum=3
```

By default [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) set the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so you can just use:

```
curl -d "pageNum=3" "https://services27.ieee.org/fellowsdirectory/getpageresultsdesk.html"
```

Comment: Thanks. How to print the raw request that the python code sent out?

Comment: @user1424739 check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658572/python-requests-print-entire-http-request-raw)

Comment: It sounds requests_toolbelt.utils.dump is the best solution. Is it?