# Python requests: figuring out request full size

Tags: python, request

How to get full size of **request** sent with Python requests (I'm not asking for response)
Should I simply add length of `body` (if apply) and `headers`?
Is something more what need to be considerate regarding request elements?

This apply for any **request** sent (GET, POST, DELETE) I wish to compute its size.

Comment: is it a post request?

Comment: if it is a POST request, then you can get the length of request from the headers

Comment: by "full size" are you talking about the length of the received HTTP?

Comment: @Stack Any request (POST, GET, DELETE, HEAD)

Comment: @Fozoro I'm asking about the size of sent request

Comment: Why don’t you just use len()

Comment: len() of what? Headers, body (if apply)? Something more should be taken under consideration like options of url?

Comment: @pbaranski check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23816211/8150371

Answer (score 5):

Short answer - size of request is sum of mainly size of method, URL, headers and body (if apply) so in approximation it will be:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get')

method_len = len(response.request.method)
url_len = len(response.request.url)
headers_len = len('\r\n'.join('{}{}'.format(k, v) for k, v in response.request.headers.items()))
body_len = len(response.request.body if response.request.body else [])

print(f'Request size {method_len + url_len + headers_len + body_len}')
```

If anything more apply please post comment.

Resources:

RFC documentation https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3

`request` library repository member response:
https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/4694

@Stack comment to this question where he mention [Python requests - print entire http request (raw)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658572/python-requests-print-entire-http-request-raw/23816211#23816211)

Question about URI: [Is URL a part of request size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50944283/is-url-a-part-of-request-size/50944803#50944803)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @pbaranski's answer.

This would work for httpx. Recording both request and response data usage:

```py
async def measure_data_usage(self, res: httpx.Response):
    # get size of req
    method_len = len(res.request.method)
    url_len = len('\r\n'.join(f'{value}' for value in res.request.url.raw))
    headers_len = len('\r\n'.join(f'{key}{value}'
                                  for key, value in
                                  res.request.headers.items()))
    body_len = len(res.request.content if res.request.content else ())
    total_req_size = method_len + url_len + headers_len + body_len

    # get size of resp
    url_len = len('\r\n'.join(f'{value}' for value in res.request.url.raw))
    headers_len = len('\r\n'.join(f'{key}{value}'
                                  for key, value in
                                  res.headers.items()))
    body_len = len(res.request.content if res.content else ())
    total_resp_size = url_len + headers_len + body_len
```

There's repetition. You can feel free to optimize according to your program. I'm leaving it in for clarity.