# Is URL a part of request size?

Tags: performance, http, performance-testing

Just wondering if URL, what can be very big ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)), is counted as part of HTTP request size, since its values are send to server (specially with query string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the target of the request is part of the message sent to the server:

```
GET /hello.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: text/plain
```

From the [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230), which defines the message syntax and routing of the HTTP/1.1 protocol:

> [**3.1.1.  Request Line**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1)
>
> A request-line begins with a method token, followed by a single space
> (SP), the request-target, another single space (SP), the protocol
> version, and ends with CRLF. [...]
>
> HTTP does not place a predefined limit on the length of a request-line [...]
>
> A server that receives a request-target longer than any URI it wishes to parse MUST respond with a `414` (URI Too Long) status code [...]
>
> Various ad hoc limitations on request-line length are found in practice.  It is RECOMMENDED that all HTTP senders and recipients support, at a minimum, request-line lengths of 8000 octets.