# OS dependent behavior of requests post

Tags: python, http, python-requests

When I run the same python code:

```py
url = 'http://lasp.colorado.edu/minxss/beacon/fileupload.php'
file_to_send = {'filename': (filename, open(filename, 'rb'))}
r = requests.post(url, files=file_to_send)
print(r.text)
```

I get different results dependent on OS. In macOS and Linux, the `r.text` is:

```
<html><head><title>MinXSS HAM Radio Beacon Upload</title></head><body>
<form method='post' action='fileupload.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'[>
Select File: <input type='file' name='filename' size='10' />
<input type='submit' value='Upload' />
</form><br/>Uploaded file '2018-10-13T14_35_30.371095_SFJPM86_40.241_-105.2353.dat'<br/></body></html>
```

but on Windows it's:

```
<html><head><title>MinXSS HAM Radio Beacon Upload</title></head><body>\n
<form method='post' action='fileupload.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'[>\n
Select File: <input type='file' name='filename' size='10' />\n
<input type='submit' value='Upload' />
</form></body></html>
```

[Here is an example file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/40trq3sgu5hdwot/2018-10-15T11_05_06.783337_SFJPM86_40.241_-105.2353.dat?dl=0) to upload.

When I check the server, the files do actually successfully upload for macOS and Linux but not for Windows. When I go to the fileupload.php script on the server in any browser in macOS or Windows, I can upload the files that were generated on any OS successfully. It seems there must be something different in `requests` on Windows.

Following @james's suggestion, I've used the `request.Request().prepare()` to see what's being sent. Here are the results from macOS (which works with the server):

```
In [4]: prep.method
Out[4]:  'POST'
In [5]: prep.url
Out[5]: 'http://lasp.colorado.edu/minxss/beacon/fileupload.php'
In [6]: prep.headers
Out[6]: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=710071eb200fc5f402d3a45b71e8289b', 'Content-Length': '2090'}
In [8]: prep.body
Out[8]: b'--710071eb200fc5f402d3a45b71e8289b\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"; filename="/Users/jmason86/MinXSS_Beacon_Decoder/output/2018-10-18T22_18_37.345945_SFJPM86_40.240_-105.2353.dat"\r\n\r\n\xc0\x00\x9a\x92\x00\xb0\xa6d`\x86\xa2@@@@\xe1\x03\xf0\x08\x19\xc1o\x00\xf7\xf14\xd6EG\x02\n\x86K\x00\x0c\x00\x01\x00.t\x01\x030\x03\x00\x03y\x00\x00\x01\xfa\xc7\x10\x01\x03\x00\x00\x01Z\x80\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x92\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00_\x00G\x13\x00\x00\n\x80\xf6\x01\xe2\x03\xd3\x0b\x06\x08\x90\x18\x05\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x8e\x01\x13\x00m\x00\x00d\x88\x01\x00\x00\xac%\x01\x00\x07\x0b \x17@\x15\x90\x15\x80\x17@\x18\xe0\xceXa\x08\x00x\x07\x08\x00\x80\x06\x08\x000\x06\x18\x00P 0\x01\x90\r\x18\x00x\x13M\x05D\x05Q\x05\t\x08\x14\x00\x9e\x05l\x00\xa0\x05\xf3\x01\\\x00O\x02R\x02S\x01S\x013\x01\x00\x00\x08\x01\x00\x00~\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc7/ \x12\xd8\x00\x00\x00\x05\x07\x02\x00\x00\x00\'\x06\x00\x00\t\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfc\xff\xfd\xff\x07\x00\x07I\x00\x00\xe5\xf9\xa5\xa5\xc0\x08\x19\xfd[\x00\xf78\x8e\x1cFk\x01\x04\xfdr\x00\x83\n\xf9\x05\tn\x02\x05\xbev\x00\x03\x12\x8f\x00\x01\x06\x90\x00\x01\xd1g\x00\x01\xca\xd8e\x01\x9f]\x02\x90\xbav\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x01\xd2\x06\x04\x08\x00\x00\x00\x01\xfc\x8ee\xb4\x00\x00\x00\x00O\x13\x00\x00\x05\x80\xe3\x01\xbc\x03\xc3\x0b\x03\x08@\x0c\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf2\xb8\x10\x00B\xd1\x059&+\x01\x00\x80\xa5\xc8\x02\x07\x0b\x90\x08\xa0\x08 \x0c\x90\x1f`\x1e\xd0\xc7\x00B\x0c\x01\xdcA0\x04(&\x10\x01`@x&\x98\x1f@\x01\xa0\r\x98\x03p\x13\x02\x06\x0b\x06\xe3\x05\xcd\x07s\x00r\x05\x14\x00w\x05\xf5\x01\x16\x00L\x02J\x02B\x01B\x013\x01\x16\x00\x99\x00\x00\x00\x9a\x00\x00\x00\xa2\xda\x1f\x00X\xfb\x14\x02c\x01\x10\x00\xca\x08\xc6/\x13\x06&\xfd\xff\x00\x15\x04\x06\x00\x00\x00%\r*\x05\xbf\x05\xe1\x01e\x01\x99\x02\xfd\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x07\xd6\x00\x00\xa3\xda\xa5\xa5\x08\x19\xfd\x91\x00\xf7\xda\x8e\x1cF\xae\x01\x04\xfdr\x00\x83\n\xf9\x05$n\x02\x05\xbev\x00\x03\x12\x8f\x00\x01H\x91\x00\x01\xd1g\x00\x01A\xd9e\x01\x9f]\x02\x90\xbav\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x01\xd2\x06\x04\x08\x00\x00\x00\x01\xfc\x8ee\xb7\x00\x00\x00\x00O\x13\x00\x00\x05\x80\xe3\x01\xbb\x03\xbe\x0b\x04\x08\xd0\x0c\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\xb9\x10\x00S\xd1\x05X&+\x01\x00\xfa\xa8\xc8\x02\x07\x0b@\t@\t\xb0\x0c  \xe0\x1e\xe0\xc7\xdeB\x10\x01\x10B@\x04(&\x10\x01\xb8@\x10&\xa0\x1fH\x01\xa0\r\x98\x03p\x13\x01\x06\r\x06\xdc\x05\xca\x07l\x00v\x05\x16\x00w\x05\xf5\x01\x19\x00M\x02J\x02B\x01C\x013\x01\x17\x00\xa1\x00\x00\x00\xa6\x00\x00\x00\x19\xdf\x1f\x00Q\xfb\xeb\x01<\x01\r\x00\xca\x08\xc6/\x14\x07&\xfc\x00\x00\x15\x04\x06\x00\x00\x00%\r*\x05\xbf\x05\x19\x01\x8b\x00w\x02\xfd\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07x\x00\x00\x88z\xa5\xa5\x08\x19\xfaJ\x00\xf7\xed\xc4\x1eF\xe0\x00\x04\xfdi\x00\xc5\n\x11\x06\x81\xcc\x02\x05\xd5v\x00\x03\x12\x8f\x00\x01\x89\xfc\x00\x01\xd1g\x00\x01\x9de\x00\x01?Y\x02\x90\xb6v\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xc5\x00\x00\x00\x00O\x13\x00\x00\x05\x80\xe0\x01\x0c\x03\xdc\x0b\x04\x08`\x05\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x91\x10\r\x00d\t\x06V^8\x01\x00\xf4\x17\xe6\x02\x07\x0b\xf0\x01\xb0\x01\x00\x05\x90\x19\x90\x18\xb0\xc6\xff7`\x01\x18B \x04\x10&H\x01\x80@@+\x80\x1f@\x01\xa0\rP\x03p\x13\x00\x06\x03\x06\xd7\x05\xbf\x07\x99\x00o\x05\x17\x00v\x05\xf5\x01\x05\x00L\x02J\x02>\x01>\x013\x01\x0f\x00\x07\x01\x00\x00\\\x00\x00\x00\xd2\xa2\x1f\x00g\xfb\x17\x02\x86\x03p\x00\xca\x08\xc7/\n\x04\'\xfd\xff\x00\x1a\x04\x06\x00\x00\x00\x08\x03\xae\x04\xa8\x04\xf2\x02\r\x04\x82\xfc\xfc\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x8b\x00\x00ra\xa5\xa5\xc0\x00\x9a\x92\x00\xb0\xa6d`\x86\xa2@@@@\xe1\x03\xf0\x08\x19\xc1o\x00\xf7\xf14\xd6EG\x02\n\x86K\x00\x0c\x00\x01\x00.t\x01\x030\x03\x00\x03y\x00\x00\x01\xfa\xc7\x10\x01\x03\x00\x00\x01Z\x80\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x92\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00_\x00G\x13\x00\x00\n\x80\xf6\x01\xe2\x03\xd3\x0b\x06\x08\x90\x18\x05\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x8e\x01\x13\x00m\x00\x00d\x88\x01\x00\x00\xac%\x01\x00\x07\x0b \x17@\x15\x90\x15\x80\x17@\x18\xe0\xceXa\x08\x00x\x07\x08\x00\x80\x06\x08\x000\x06\x18\x00P 0\x01\x90\r\x18\x00x\x13M\x05D\x05Q\x05\t\x08\x14\x00\x9e\x05l\x00\xa0\x05\xf3\x01\\\x00O\x02R\x02S\x01S\x013\x01\x00\x00\x08\x01\x00\x00~\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc7/ \x12\xd8\x00\x00\x00\x05\x07\x02\x00\x00\x00\'\x06\x00\x00\t\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfc\xff\xfd\xff\x07\x00\x07I\x00\x00\xe5\xf9\xa5\xa5\xc0\x00\x86\xa2@@@@`\x9a\x92\x9c\xb0\xa6\xa6\xe1\x03\xf0\x08\x19\xdd\x04\x00\xf7\x1f?)FE\x03\x02\xd6\xe1\x00\x1c\x00\x0b\x00\xea\x86\x04\x05\x03\x94\x00\x03\x12\x8f\x00\x01\xb3\x0f\x00\x01\xd1g\x00\x01`\xc7\x06\x01\x00\x00\x00\x90\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x9f\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x13\x00\x00\x05\x80\xe1\x01\xb9\x03\xc3\x0b\x02\x08 \xfe\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00b\x16\x0b\x00\x9d\x08\x00a\x9d\x05\x00\x00\xa4\xe6\r\x00\x07\x0bp\xfd\x10\xf9@\xfc\x90\x0c`\x0bp\xc7w5\x00\x01XDH\x04 &\xe8\x00\xc8C\xa0$\x90\x1f8\x01\xa0\r\x18\x00\x80\x13\xbd\x05\xdc\x05\xb0\x05\xc0\x07\xb4\x00_\x05\x15\x00\\\x05\xf5\x01\xed\x03K\x02I\x028\x019\x013\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x006\x00\x00\x00\xabn\x17\x00#&x&\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc7/\x03\x01\'\xff\xff\x00\x0c\x13\x02\x00\x00\x009\x05d\x05t\x04\x92\x01\xe9\x00q\x03\xec\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x07"\x00\x00\xccC\xa5\xa5\xc0\x86\xa2@@@@`\x9a\x92\x9c\xb0\xa6\xa6\xe1\x03\xf0\x08\x19\xc6\x16\x00\xf7\x86\xf97F`\x01\x01\x00K\x00\xba\x00\xc9\x00t\xfc\x00\x05\xa2\x94\x00\x03\x12\x8f\x00\x01d\x93\x03\x01\xd1g\x00\x01\xfej\x0f\x01f\x9b\x00\x90\x80\x94\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x01\xd2\x06\x04\x08\x00\x00\x00\x01o\xd4\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x13\x00\x00\x05\x80\xc7\x01\x85\x03\xd5\x0b\x02\x080E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12L%\x00\t~\x01r#<\x00\x00\xe2\x9f\xda\x01\x07\x0b\xe0<\xb0F\x00A\xf0<0<0\xbbx\x10\x08\x00h\x05h\x00\xa8!\xa0\x01\x80"\xb8\tX\x1d\x08\x01\xa8\r(\x00\x80\x13\xa0\x0b\xa6\x07\x00\x08\x85\x075\x00\x91\x05\x15\x00\x91\x05\xf6\x01\xb7\x00|\x01\x00\x00g\x01h\x013\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc7/\x0c\r\xd8\x00\x00\x00\x03\t\x01\x00\x00\x00\xa8\x07\xbc\x0b\xd0\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa4\x02\x1e\xfe\xb2\xfd\x07$\x00\x00\xac\xc3\xa5\xa5\r\n--710071eb200fc5f402d3a45b71e8289b--\r\n'
```

and for Windows 10 (which doesn't work):

```
In [4]: prep.method
Out[4]: 'POST'
In [5]: prep.url
Out[5]: 'http://lasp.colorado.edu/minxss/beacon/fileupload.php'
In [6]: prep.headers
Out[6]: {'Content-Length': '2110', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=b265e5a28299261d61cd62ccd90fc9cc'}
In [8]: prep.body
Out[8]: b'--b265e5a28299261d61cd62ccd90fc9cc\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"; filename*=utf-8\'\'C%3A%5CUsers%5Cjmason86%5CMinXSS_Beacon_Decoder%5Coutput%5C2018-10-18T21_55_12.752626_SFJPM86_40.240_-105.2353.dat\r\n\r\n\xc0\x00\x9a\x92\x00\xb0\xa6d`\x86\xa2@@@@\xe1\x03\xf0\x08\x19\xc1o\x00\xf7\xf14\xd6EG\x02\n\x86K\x00\x0c\x00\x01\x00.t\x01\x030\x03\x00\x03y\x00\x00\x01\xfa\xc7\x10\x01\x03\x00\x00\x01Z\x80\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x92\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00_\x00G\x13\x00\x00\n\x80\xf6\x01\xe2\x03\xd3\x0b\x06\x08\x90\x18\x05\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x8e\x01\x13\x00m\x00\x00d\x88\x01\x00\x00\xac%\x01\x00\x07\x0b \x17@\x15\x90\x15\x80\x17@\x18\xe0\xceXa\x08\x00x\x07\x08\x00\x80\x06\x08\x000\x06\x18\x00P 0\x01\x90\r\x18\x00x\x13M\x05D\x05Q\x05\t\x08\x14\x00\x9e\x05l\x00\xa0\x05\xf3\x01\\\x00O\x02R\x02S\x01S\x013\x01\x00\x00\x08\x01\x00\x00~\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc7/ \x12\xd8\x00\x00\x00\x05\x07\x02\x00\x00\x00\'\x06\x00\x00\t\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfc\xff\xfd\xff\x07\x00\x07I\x00\x00\xe5\xf9\xa5\xa5\xc0\x08\x19\xfd[\x00\xf78\x8e\x1cFk\x01\x04\xfdr\x00\x83\n\xf9\x05\tn\x02\x05\xbev\x00\x03\x12\x8f\x00\x01\x06\x90\x00\x01\xd1g\x00\x01\xca\xd8e\x01\x9f]\x02\x90\xbav\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x01\xd2\x06\x04\x08\x00\x00\x00\x01\xfc\x8ee\xb4\x00\x00\x00\x00O\x13\x00\x00\x05\x80\xe3\x01\xbc\x03\xc3\x0b\x03\x08@\x0c\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf2\xb8\x10\x00B\xd1\x059&+\x01\x00\x80\xa5\xc8\x02\x07\x0b\x90\x08\xa0\x08 \x0c\x90\x1f`\x1e\xd0\xc7\x00B\x0c\x01\xdcA0\x04(&\x10\x01`@x&\x98\x1f@\x01\xa0\r\x98\x03p\x13\x02\x06\x0b\x06\xe3\x05\xcd\x07s\x00r\x05\x14\x00w\x05\xf5\x01\x16\x00L\x02J\x02B\x01B\x013\x01\x16\x00\x99\x00\x00\x00\x9a\x00\x00\x00\xa2\xda\x1f\x00X\xfb\x14\x02c\x01\x10\x00\xca\x08\xc6/\x13\x06&\xfd\xff\x00\x15\x04\x06\x00\x00\x00%\r*\x05\xbf\x05\xe1\x01e\x01\x99\x02\xfd\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x07\xd6\x00\x00\xa3\xda\xa5\xa5\x08\x19\xfd\x91\x00\xf7\xda\x8e\x1cF\xae\x01\x04\xfdr\x00\x83\n\xf9\x05$n\x02\x05\xbev\x00\x03\x12\x8f\x00\x01H\x91\x00\x01\xd1g\x00\x01A\xd9e\x01\x9f]\x02\x90\xbav\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x01\xd2\x06\x04\x08\x00\x00\x00\x01\xfc\x8ee\xb7\x00\x00\x00\x00O\x13\x00\x00\x05\x80\xe3\x01\xbb\x03\xbe\x0b\x04\x08\xd0\x0c\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\xb9\x10\x00S\xd1\x05X&+\x01\x00\xfa\xa8\xc8\x02\x07\x0b@\t@\t\xb0\x0c  \xe0\x1e\xe0\xc7\xdeB\x10\x01\x10B@\x04(&\x10\x01\xb8@\x10&\xa0\x1fH\x01\xa0\r\x98\x03p\x13\x01\x06\r\x06\xdc\x05\xca\x07l\x00v\x05\x16\x00w\x05\xf5\x01\x19\x00M\x02J\x02B\x01C\x013\x01\x17\x00\xa1\x00\x00\x00\xa6\x00\x00\x00\x19\xdf\x1f\x00Q\xfb\xeb\x01<\x01\r\x00\xca\x08\xc6/\x14\x07&\xfc\x00\x00\x15\x04\x06\x00\x00\x00%\r*\x05\xbf\x05\x19\x01\x8b\x00w\x02\xfd\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07x\x00\x00\x88z\xa5\xa5\x08\x19\xfaJ\x00\xf7\xed\xc4\x1eF\xe0\x00\x04\xfdi\x00\xc5\n\x11\x06\x81\xcc\x02\x05\xd5v\x00\x03\x12\x8f\x00\x01\x89\xfc\x00\x01\xd1g\x00\x01\x9de\x00\x01?Y\x02\x90\xb6v\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xc5\x00\x00\x00\x00O\x13\x00\x00\x05\x80\xe0\x01\x0c\x03\xdc\x0b\x04\x08`\x05\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x91\x10\r\x00d\t\x06V^8\x01\x00\xf4\x17\xe6\x02\x07\x0b\xf0\x01\xb0\x01\x00\x05\x90\x19\x90\x18\xb0\xc6\xff7`\x01\x18B \x04\x10&H\x01\x80@@+\x80\x1f@\x01\xa0\rP\x03p\x13\x00\x06\x03\x06\xd7\x05\xbf\x07\x99\x00o\x05\x17\x00v\x05\xf5\x01\x05\x00L\x02J\x02>\x01>\x013\x01\x0f\x00\x07\x01\x00\x00\\\x00\x00\x00\xd2\xa2\x1f\x00g\xfb\x17\x02\x86\x03p\x00\xca\x08\xc7/\n\x04\'\xfd\xff\x00\x1a\x04\x06\x00\x00\x00\x08\x03\xae\x04\xa8\x04\xf2\x02\r\x04\x82\xfc\xfc\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x8b\x00\x00ra\xa5\xa5\xc0\x00\x9a\x92\x00\xb0\xa6d`\x86\xa2@@@@\xe1\x03\xf0\x08\x19\xc1o\x00\xf7\xf14\xd6EG\x02\n\x86K\x00\x0c\x00\x01\x00.t\x01\x030\x03\x00\x03y\x00\x00\x01\xfa\xc7\x10\x01\x03\x00\x00\x01Z\x80\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x92\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00_\x00G\x13\x00\x00\n\x80\xf6\x01\xe2\x03\xd3\x0b\x06\x08\x90\x18\x05\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x8e\x01\x13\x00m\x00\x00d\x88\x01\x00\x00\xac%\x01\x00\x07\x0b \x17@\x15\x90\x15\x80\x17@\x18\xe0\xceXa\x08\x00x\x07\x08\x00\x80\x06\x08\x000\x06\x18\x00P 0\x01\x90\r\x18\x00x\x13M\x05D\x05Q\x05\t\x08\x14\x00\x9e\x05l\x00\xa0\x05\xf3\x01\\\x00O\x02R\x02S\x01S\x013\x01\x00\x00\x08\x01\x00\x00~\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc7/ \x12\xd8\x00\x00\x00\x05\x07\x02\x00\x00\x00\'\x06\x00\x00\t\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfc\xff\xfd\xff\x07\x00\x07I\x00\x00\xe5\xf9\xa5\xa5\xc0\x00\x86\xa2@@@@`\x9a\x92\x9c\xb0\xa6\xa6\xe1\x03\xf0\x08\x19\xdd\x04\x00\xf7\x1f?)FE\x03\x02\xd6\xe1\x00\x1c\x00\x0b\x00\xea\x86\x04\x05\x03\x94\x00\x03\x12\x8f\x00\x01\xb3\x0f\x00\x01\xd1g\x00\x01`\xc7\x06\x01\x00\x00\x00\x90\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x9f\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x13\x00\x00\x05\x80\xe1\x01\xb9\x03\xc3\x0b\x02\x08 \xfe\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00b\x16\x0b\x00\x9d\x08\x00a\x9d\x05\x00\x00\xa4\xe6\r\x00\x07\x0bp\xfd\x10\xf9@\xfc\x90\x0c`\x0bp\xc7w5\x00\x01XDH\x04 &\xe8\x00\xc8C\xa0$\x90\x1f8\x01\xa0\r\x18\x00\x80\x13\xbd\x05\xdc\x05\xb0\x05\xc0\x07\xb4\x00_\x05\x15\x00\\\x05\xf5\x01\xed\x03K\x02I\x028\x019\x013\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x006\x00\x00\x00\xabn\x17\x00#&x&\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc7/\x03\x01\'\xff\xff\x00\x0c\x13\x02\x00\x00\x009\x05d\x05t\x04\x92\x01\xe9\x00q\x03\xec\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x07"\x00\x00\xccC\xa5\xa5\xc0\x86\xa2@@@@`\x9a\x92\x9c\xb0\xa6\xa6\xe1\x03\xf0\x08\x19\xc6\x16\x00\xf7\x86\xf97F`\x01\x01\x00K\x00\xba\x00\xc9\x00t\xfc\x00\x05\xa2\x94\x00\x03\x12\x8f\x00\x01d\x93\x03\x01\xd1g\x00\x01\xfej\x0f\x01f\x9b\x00\x90\x80\x94\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x01\xd2\x06\x04\x08\x00\x00\x00\x01o\xd4\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x13\x00\x00\x05\x80\xc7\x01\x85\x03\xd5\x0b\x02\x080E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12L%\x00\t~\x01r#<\x00\x00\xe2\x9f\xda\x01\x07\x0b\xe0<\xb0F\x00A\xf0<0<0\xbbx\x10\x08\x00h\x05h\x00\xa8!\xa0\x01\x80"\xb8\tX\x1d\x08\x01\xa8\r(\x00\x80\x13\xa0\x0b\xa6\x07\x00\x08\x85\x075\x00\x91\x05\x15\x00\x91\x05\xf6\x01\xb7\x00|\x01\x00\x00g\x01h\x013\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc7/\x0c\r\xd8\x00\x00\x00\x03\t\x01\x00\x00\x00\xa8\x07\xbc\x0b\xd0\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa4\x02\x1e\xfe\xb2\xfd\x07$\x00\x00\xac\xc3\xa5\xa5\r\n--b265e5a28299261d61cd62ccd90fc9cc--\r\n'
```

That `prep.body` `filename*=` in the Windows one looks suspicious to me.

Comment: Is anything else different between your two systems? Are you running the same version of Python? Of `requests`?

Comment: Same version of `requests` but slightly different build and version of python:
* macOS requests version: 2.19.1 (py35_1 conda-forge)
* Windows requests version: 2.19.1 (py37_0)

Comment: Created a new environment with the same exact version of python and version/build of `requests` on Windows to match on macOS. No change in the results.

Comment: you print out as bytes instead of str, try this `print(b"ok\n")` ,  `print("ok\n")`. btw it will get different output between sublime and cmd.

Comment: I'm printing out the same way in all operating systems, including through the same IDE (debug terminal in PyCharm), so that shouldn't account for the difference in output.

Comment: Is this over https or http?

Comment: Can you give us something to reproduce the behaviour? If you see a different response from the server, then it wasn't `requests` doing that, that's the server.

Comment: I'll update the question with stuff to reproduce soon. What confuses me is that the server behaves the same way when I upload from a browser on macOS or WIndows and I'm literally running the exact same python code on both OS's but getting different results.

Comment: It's over http, not https

Comment: Updated question so there's enough to try reproducing now (I think). Let me know if not.

Comment: Using the technique described here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658572/python-requests-print-entire-http-request-raw can you dump the raw request being sent from each OS and post the headers from those raw requests in your question (or use Wireshark to achieve the same)

Comment: Appears to work on Windows 7 for me (got `...Uploaded file '2018-10-15T11_05_06.783337_SFJPM86_40.241_-105.2353.dat'...`).  Python 3.7.0, requests 2.19.1, urllib3 1.23.

Comment: Weird that WIndows 7 has no problem. @James, I've updated my question with the results of this comparison. Definitely some differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I initially could not replicate this problem on Windows 7 when I used `filename = '2018-10-15T11_05_06.783337_SFJPM86_40.241_-105.2353.dat'`.  But when I used backslashes in the filename, I could replicate it, so it seems the server does not handle that backslash version well.

This version uses slashes instead of backslashes and works for me on Windows 7:

```
import requests
filename = 'C:/cygwin/home/Ulrich Stern/code/samples/python/2018-10-15T11_05_06.783337_SFJPM86_40.241_-105.2353.dat'
url = 'http://lasp.colorado.edu/minxss/beacon/fileupload.php'
file_to_send = {'filename': (filename, open(filename, 'rb'))}
r = requests.post(url, files=file_to_send)
print(r.text)
```

James Paul Mason, Martijn Pieters, and James deserve a share of the credits for figuring this out.

Comment: That did it!!! I've run into the path separator issue so many times but it didn't occur to me this time because I thought python was handling it for me but as you said it's a limitation in the server script. Thank you! I can only award the bounty to one person but I've upvoted everyone else as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Ulrich's answer, it's not necessary to include the full path in the upload, and in many cases you wouldn't want to (as you're exposing information about your local machine file structure that the server doesn't need to know).

So a generic solution to make your code run on either OS is:

```
import os.path
location, name = os.path.split(filename)
url = 'http://lasp.colorado.edu/minxss/beacon/fileupload.php'
file_to_send = {'filename': (name, open(filename, 'rb'))}
r = requests.post(url, files=file_to_send)
print(r.text)
```