# Converting a requests request to a socket request in python

Tags: python, sockets, http, python-requests, python-sockets

I have a code akin to this:

```
import requests

endpoint = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com'
host = 's3.amazonaws.com'
bucket = 'mybucket'
key = 'mykey'
access_key = 'access'
secret_key = 'secret'

url = '/'.join([endpoint, bucket, key]) 
headers = {'Host': host, 'User-Agent': 'whatever'}
headers = get_more_amazon_headers(headers, host, bucket, key, access_key, secret_key) 

requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

This is very terse and nice, but requests is a python only library, and I was trying to convert the last line:

`requests.get(url, headers=headers)`

to be used with python's socket library, hopefully something like:

```
s3_message= ''' respective bytestring '''.encode('utf8')

socket.send(s3_message)
```

Can I somehow get the bytestring out of requests, so I can use the pattern? If not, is there some way to figure out the correct socket message?

Comment: you can watch this,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658572/python-requests-print-entire-http-request-raw

Comment: thanks, found several options there