# Node.js request - print entire http request (raw) of a post

Tags: node.js

I am using the request library in Node.js to Google's text-to-speech API. I would like to print out the request that is being sent like in this [python example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658572/python-requests-print-entire-http-request-raw).

Here is my code:

```
const request = require('request');


const headers = {headers: {'input': {'text':'I want to say this'}, 'voice':{  'languageCode' : 'en-US'},'audioConfig':{'audioEncoding': 'MP3'}}}

request.post('https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize?key=API_KEY',headers, (error, res, body) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error)
    return
  }
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
  console.log(body)
})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is documented [here](https://github.com/request/request#debugging):

> There are at least three ways to debug the operation of request:
>
> 1. Launch the node process like `NODE_DEBUG=request node script.js` (`lib`,`request`,`otherlib` works too).
> 2. Set `require('request').debug = true` at any time (this does the same thing as #1).
> 3. Use the `request-debug` module to view request and response headers and bodies.

Comment: This is incorrect.  *require('request').debug = true* does not produce raw http requests, but just some pretty-printing.

Comment: @ElSampsa I'm showing all documented debugging options. The latter (number 3) explains that it can be used to _"view request and response headers and bodies"_.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way to do this is to start a netcat server on any port:

```sh
$ nc -l -p 8080
```

and change the URL to localhost:

```
https://localhost:8080/v1beta1/text:synthesize?key=API_KEY
```

Obviously, you won't be able to see the response, but the entire raw request data will be available for you to inspect in the terminal you have netcat running

Answer (score 0):

In NodeJS:

```js
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const { rawHeaders, httpVersion, method, socket, url } = req;
  const { remoteAddress, remoteFamily } = socket;
  const data = JSON.stringify({
      timestamp: Date.now(),
      rawHeaders,
      httpVersion,
      method,
      remoteAddress,
      remoteFamily,
      url
    });

  console.info('---------------');
  console.info(data);
  res.end(data);
});

console.info('App started');
server.listen(3000);
```