# Define a triple-quoted f-string with newline-containing substrings inside a function without outputted indents

Tags: python, formatting, f-string

I'm trying to pretty-print a HTTP request (that I've mocked here).

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class RequestMock(NamedTuple):
    method = 'POST'
    url = 'https://bob.com'
    body = 'body1\nbody2'
    headers = {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}
```

I have a function that does this:

```
req = RequestMock()

def print1(req):
    headers = '\n'.join(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in req.headers.items())
    s = '\n'.join([
        f'{req.method} {req.url}',
        headers,
        req.body
    ])
    print(s)

print1(req)
# POST https://bob.com
# a: 1
# b: 2
# body1
# body2
```

But when I've tried to rewrite it with `f-strings` for clarity and ease of modification, I get some bad indents:

```
# what I want the code to look like
def print2(req):
    headers = '\n'.join(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in req.headers.items())
    s = f"""
    {req.method} {req.url}
    {headers}
    {req.body}
    """
    print(s)

print2(req)
#     POST https://bob.com
#     a: 1
# b: 2
#     body1
# body2
```

I know this is because I'm defining strings with newlines and putting them in a triple-quoted string. Is there a simple way to get the output I'm looking with a triple-quoted `f-string` defined in a function and without having to know the indentation level of its definition? I've played with `textwrap.indent`, `textwrap.dedent`, `str.lstrip`, `re`, etc., but the code stops being simple and pythonic fast. The closest thing I've come up with is the following, but the length is awkward and I feel like I'm repeating myself.

```
def print3(req):
    headers = '\n'.join(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in req.headers.items())
    s = textwrap.dedent("""
    {method} {url}
    {headers}
    {body}
    """).strip()
    s = s.format(
        method=req.method,
        url=req.url,
        headers=headers,
        body=req.body,
    )
    print(s)
print3(req)
# POST https://bob.com
# a: 1
# b: 2
# body1
# body2
```

Comment: Note: I went down this rabbit-hole trying to make [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23816211/2958070) more readable

Comment: You could just link together normal python strings inside the parenthesis of the `print()`. That way you can add more just by pressing enter.

Comment: @GeeTransit what I'm really interested in is the slightly more general idea of *formatting* strings. Then I can pass them a round as  I please.

Comment: `'\n'.join(line.lstrip() for line in f'''insert \n multiline \n string \n here \n {variable}'''.split('\n'))`

Comment: Looks unpythonic inside a comment... It uses triple quoted `f-strings` so you can just add the part at the front, leave the middle, and add the ending `.split('\n')`.

Comment: Eh, I'll put it inside an answer so you'll understand better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can try to take advantage of implicit string concatenation for a semi-nice looking solution:

```
def print4(req):
    headers = '\n'.join(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in req.headers.items())
    s = (f'{req.method} {req.url}\n'
         f'{headers}\n'
         f'{req.body}')
    print(s)

print4(req)
```

Output:

```
POST https://bob.com
a: 1
b: 2
body1
body2
```

Note that, if you want, you can take out the parentheses and use backslashes:

```
s = f'{req.method} {req.url}\n' \
    f'{headers}\n'              \
    f'{req.body}'
```

However, the style guide prefers parentheses over backslashes.

---

Another option:

```
def print5(req):
    headers = '\n'.join(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in req.headers.items())
    s = f"""
    {req.method} {req.url}
    {headers}
    {req.body}
    """
    s = '\n'.join(l.lstrip() for l in s.splitlines())
    print(s)
```

Comment: Instead of `s = '\n'.join(l.lstrip() for l in s.splitlines())`, try `s = textwrap.dedent(s)` from the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it with 2 tiny changes:

```
def print6(req, **w):
    headers = '\n'.join(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in req.headers.items())
    method, url, body = \
        w['method'], w['url'], w['body']
    #   < note the changes belowwwwwwwwwwww >
    s = '\n'.join(line.lstrip() for line in f"""
    {method} {url}
    {headers}
    {body}
    """.split('\n')) # and note this .split('\n') over here
    print(s)
print6(req)
```

Comment: This prints `{method} {url}\n{headers}\n{body}`.

Comment: Whoops... Forgot the `f` before the triple quote. Hah.

Comment: `NameError: name 'method' is not defined` It should be `req.method`, `req.url`, etc. I think.

Comment: You can define it outside the function. I can change it so it'll get the names from inside it though. EDIT: Nvm, I've checked his question again. I need to focus more :D

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I know this question was posted *AGES* ago, but I came here cos I had the same question. The answer I've come with is to use the templating module `jinja2` - mostly cos I kinda know it :) here's a great [start guide](https://realpython.com/primer-on-jinja-templating/). It's also not massively different from `f` string templates, ish.

Obv, if you don't want the indenting, then just don't use it in the triple-quote string.

Here's an example where I use triple-quotes to define the `jinja2` template, set up the I you want in a dictionary, then merge the dictionary into the template. The parameters to `render()` are similar to the older `"".format()`, but I like doing it this way.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import jinja2

my_template = """<html>
    <body>
        {{ data.item_one }}
    <P>
        {{ data.item_two }}
    </body>
</html>
"""

my_dict = { "data" : {
    "item_one": "This is line one",
    "item_two": "This is line two"
    }
}

environment = jinja2.Environment()
template = environment.from_string(my_template)
print(template.render(**my_dict))
```

then run it

```
$ ./jin.py
<html>
        <body>
                This is line one
        <P>
                This is line two
        </body>
</html>
```