# How to get the request.post string that im sending?

Tags: python-requests

hope you can help me on with this issue that i've been trying to solve within the last 2 weeks and i finallly gave up on reading the requests documentation. I happen to think that what i need is very simple, but somehow i have not been able to solve it.

I have the following code:

import requests

a=requests.post(url, params)

How do i know the http string that im **sending?**

What i need to do is to get the string so I can make a signature with a secret key, add it to the parameters and make the post with the signature as a new parameter.  So, i know the methods and the paremeters in order to post, but I dont know that the request.post makes to those objects. It would be something like this:

```
what_i_send=request.post(url, params)
signature=signature_method(what_i_send)
params["signature"]=signature
final_request=request.post(url,params)
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: You mean you need to dump the HTTP request?

Comment: I dont know if that's the name of the method that im looking for, probably yes. What i need this for is to make a signature with the code that im sending so i can add it as a parameter in the final post that im sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23816211/6580047) neat function and print something like this:

```py
def print_request(req):
    print('{}\r\n{}\r\n\r\n{}'.format(
        req.method + ' ' + req.url,
        '\r\n'.join('{}: {}'.format(k, v) for k, v in req.headers.items()),
        req.body,
    ))

a = requests.post(url, params)
print_request(a.request)
```