# How to get entire size of request message in python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to see how many bytes were sent out to the server when making an HTTP request.

```
import requests

resp = requests.get("http://www.example.com")

print(resp.request)
>>> <PreparedRequest [GET]>
```

How can I get the number of bytes contained in `<PreparedRequest [GET]>` including any attached files, payloads, etc.

Comment: @MendelG Please re-read the question.

Comment: Are you interested in determining the total raw byte count for the request, or is it enough to know the sizes of the useful payload portions of the request?

Comment: @Steve Currently trying to analyze traffic of a particular library. Trying to get an **APPROXIMATE** value for number of bytes outbound/inbound. I am using `len(resp.content)` for inbound. Don't know how to do outbound correctly right now.

Comment: If you want to get pretty much the exact size of the request, including all the structure, I think this question/answers might do it for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658572/python-requests-print-entire-http-request-raw.

Comment: If you want more of an approximation, then knowing the structure of what you're sending will let you get that.  You mention a GET request as an example.  A GET request has no body.  PUT and POST requests have a body, but you should know what you're putting in there, so you should know the size.  I guess there could be cases where the body of a PUT or POST is being constructed for you and so you don't know just how big they are, but I think you can get at the Content-Length header once the request is sent to get the size of the request body.

Comment: @Steve Really, there is no in-built method to calculate such a trivial property? I have to compute it by hand using the RFC? This is absurd...

Comment: I was just looking at that URL I gave you above, and the Requests docs.  I think you can get the exact size of the payload once you've sent the request via `len(resp.request.content)` or maybe `len(resp.request.text)`.  For a GET request, these two fields will both be `None`, as a GET doesn't have a body.

Comment: I agree with @Steve 's answer. Otherwise you can calculate the size of your payload before sending request by converting it into bytes or something else which you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question. Although it is not perfect and has several scenarios in which it fails to account for edge cases, it works for my needs.

```py
def rlen(response):
    """
    approximate request size sent to server
    """
    len_of_meth = len(response.request.method)
    len_of_addr = len(response.request.url)
    len_of_head = len('\r\n'.join('{}{}'.format(k, v) for k, v in response.request.headers.items()))
    len_of_body = len(response.request.body if response.request.body else [])

    return len_of_meth + len_of_addr + len_of_head + len_of_body
```

Answer (score 0):

len(resp.content) should work !