# Determine URL associated with POST request sent in Python

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I just created an API using Flask on Heroku (POST request). I understand how to send a request and print out the results, but I would like to know what the full URL is that is being sent so I can use the API outside of Python. I'd imagine it should be something like apiurl.com/id=3&url=url.com&.... As a test example, I've created https://test-my-flask0.herokuapp.com/ which just takes a single number and adds 2 to it. For example:

```
import json 
import requests

url = "https://test-my-flask0.herokuapp.com/"
data = 2
data = json.dumps(data)
send_request = requests.post(url, data)

print(send_request)
>> <Response [200]>

print(send_request.json())
>> {'results': {'results': 4.0}}
```

What's a flexible way I could get the URL that's being sent to create such a request? My actual API is a bit more complex with strings and arrays and such as inputs, so I'm needing a flexible way to determine the associated URL. Sorry if I'm using unclear terminology- this is my first API. Thanks.

Comment: Ummm `send_request.url`?

Comment: That shows the url where the API is (https://test-my-flask0.herokuapp.com/) but does not add in the parameters (something like https://test-my-flask0.herokuapp.com/?param=2 or whatever it would be)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20658572/5345646).