# Python Requests body doesn't match what I put as the body

Tags: python, python-requests, roblox

The title might not make sense but my problem is that I have set something as the body in the request but when I print it out it doesn't print what the actual body was.

Here is my code:

```
data = {
    "offers": [
        {
            "userId": 435771547,
            "userAssetIds": [
                2409285794
            ],
            "robux": 0
        },
        {
            "userId": userId,
            "userAssetIds": [
                1380767576
            ],
            "robux": 0
        }
    ]
}

requested = requests.post("https://trades.roblox.com/v1/trades/send", data = data, cookies = cookie, headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": token
})

print(requested.request.body)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests returns a response from `requests.post()`, and not a request itself. So usually you will write something like  `respone = requests.post(...)` and say check `response.status_code`, then read `response.json()`, etc.

To see the request itself say for the debugging purpose you could use a more low-level approach with the use of a `requests.Request()` to construct the request and then print it. You can find a good example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23816211/1203773).

Another option is to analyze the request is logging. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16630836/1203773).

By the way if you want to send a json body, use `json` keyword argument instead of `data`.

```
requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post',
              json={'a': 'hello', 'b': [1, 2, 3]})
```