# Python requests post file upload fails while Curl succeeds

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to port a working curl solution to plain python.

I'm uploading a file (pdf in this case) to a documented API endpoint:
https://developers.lexoffice.io/docs/#vouchers-endpoint-upload-a-file-to-a-voucher

The example from the documentation in curl works flawlessly:

```
retStream = os.popen('curl https://api.lexoffice.io/v1/vouchers/' + cr.json()['bookkeepingVoucherId'] + '/files -X POST'
            + ' -H "Authorization: Bearer ' + Settings.LEXOFFICE_CONFIG['api-key'] + '" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"'
            + ' -H "Accept: application/json" -F "file=@' + zfo.filename + '"')
```

Now the same in Python, it fails and gets an unspecific 500:

```
   def _it__(self, apiKey):
        self.__apiKey = apiKey
        self.__headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.__apiKey,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
[...]
    def uploadFileToAVoucher(self, voucherId, filename):
        heads = self.__headers.copy()
        heads['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data'
        print(filename)
        files = {
            'file': (filename, open(filename, 'rb'), 'application/pdf')
        }
        return requests.post(LexofficeApi.API_URL + '/v1/vouchers/' + voucherId + '/files',
                            files=files, headers=heads)
```

The API-Key is identical (and other API calls work perfectly, the basic structure must be correct). I even dumped the curl outgoing http body with `--trace-ascii` and compared it to the python request. The exact same sequence.

I have no clue what Python does differently. Any ideas?

curl trace:

```
=> Send header, 315 bytes (0x13b)
0000: POST /v1/vouchers/<removed>/files HTT
0040: P/2
0045: Host: api.lexoffice.io
005d: user-agent: curl/7.68.0
0076: authorization: Bearer <removed>
00b2: accept: application/json
00cc: content-length: 35015
00e3: content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------
0123: ----a52203785a14b388
0139: 
<= Recv SSL data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: ....@
== Info: Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
=> Send SSL data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: ....!
=> Send SSL data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: ...@.
=> Send SSL data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: ....!
=> Send SSL data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: ...@.
=> Send SSL data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: ....!
=> Send SSL data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: .....
=> Send data, 35015 bytes (0x88c7)
0000: --------------------------a52203785a14b388
002c: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="<rem
006c: moved>"
0090: Content-Type: application/pdf
00af: 
00b1: %PDF-1.4.%.....1 0 obj.<</Creator (Chromium)./Producer (Skia/PDF
00f1:  m93)./CreationDate (D:20211004001328+00'00')./ModDate (D:202110
0131: 04001328+00'00')>>.endobj.3 0 obj.<</ca 1./BM /Normal>>.endobj.5
0171:  0 obj.<</ca .9333./BM /Normal>>.endobj.8 0 obj.<</Filter /Flate
01b1: Decode./Length 6736>> stream.x..]]...q.._q..T.7E.0.k{}.....:H..E
01f1: .4n.....t..3..sL...^{..45_.g8.R..tX.y....'..l..d..........+3...
[...]
```

python request body:

```
b'--ae550894d8422832a377fdd24f109898\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="<removed>"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n%PDF-1.4\n%\xd3\xeb\xe9\xe1\n1 0 obj\n<</Creator (Chromium)\n/Producer (Skia/PDF m93)\n/CreationDate (D:20211004002626+00\'00\')\n/ModDate (D:20211004002626+00\'00\')>>\nendobj\n3 0 obj\n<</ca 1\n/BM /Normal>>\nendobj\n5 0 obj\n<</ca .9333\n/BM /Normal>>\nendobj\n8 0 obj\n<</Filter /FlateDecode\n/Length 6736>> stream\nx\x9c\xed]]\xc
```

Looks very much the same to me.

Comment: Can you print out the Python POST request, incl. headers, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23816211/530160) and add it to your question? Would be nice to compare the curl and Python ones.

Comment: When I have issues like this, I will try to find a minimal similar request that I can program "equivalent" curl-vs-python calls an make sure those short one works.  For example, requests with no auth or no arguments, and if that works, add complexity to find the breakage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requests.post` doesn't set the Content-Length, it's always 0. The LexOffice-API seems to be picky about this.

A workaround with `pycurl` works. Here's a generic version of the question:
[python requests.post header content-length always 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69457188/python-requests-post-header-content-length-always-0)