# Print out the method and headers of request I am sending

Tags: python, http, python-requests, http-headers, aiohttp

I am trying to print out the method and headers of a request I am sending. I can do it for the response of the request, but not the actual request itself.

Here's where the problem lies:

```py
async with session.get('url', params=params) as resp:
    print(resp.method)
    content = await
    resp.read()
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, it could be a duplicate of [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658572/python-requests-print-entire-http-request-raw)

Comment: @Talon that is for the requests library, not aiohttp.

Answer (score 0):

Is `request_info` what you are looking for ? See [the documentation](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientResponse.request_info) for extra details.

```py
 async with session.get('https://www.python.org/', params=params) as resp:
    print(resp.request_info)
    content = await resp.read()

> RequestInfo(url=URL('https://www.python.org/'), method='GET', headers=<CIMultiDictProxy('Host': 'www.python.org', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'User-Agent': 'Python/3.9 aiohttp/3.8.1')>, real_url=URL('https://www.python.org/'))
```