# Python "wb" write mode adding 0x0A to file

Tags: python

I'm trying to write 32 bytes of binary data to a file but an extra byte is being added

`wb` mode doesn't seem to accept a newline argument so I'm not sure what to do here.

```
str_ = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'


with open('test.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(str_)
```

You MUST view the file in a hex editor to be able to see the extra byte being added.
Hex View of the file from VIM: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8EpD.png

Comment: file has 32 bytes byt VIM shows 33 bytes. Maybe VIM add this value only on screen when it display it. What size has file before and after using VIM ? Maybe find different editor to check file - or write script which display data.

Comment: test commentdddd

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem - when I display on Linux `od test.bin`  (or `od -t x1 test.bin`) to see hex code then I see only 32 bytes without `0x0A`. And `f.write()` can't add new line.

Comment: the same is with `xxd test.bin` - it also shows only 32 bytes without `0x0A`.

Answer (score -1):

```
os.system('touch efuse.bin')
with open('efuse.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(generateBinString())
```

why you are writing newline=""

```
c=b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
with open('efuse.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(c.rstrip())

with open('efuse.bin', 'rb') as f:
    print(f.read())
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Line Feeds (0A) and Carriage Returns (0D)

[image]

CAN YOU SEE [Python file.write creating extra carriage return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025760/python-file-write-creating-extra-carriage-return)

hope it helps

Comment: rstrip doesn't work. I'm 99% sure the newline byte is being added by `f.write()`

Comment: how can i help you when i am not able to see 0a?